# SharePoint move specific WebParts to another feature using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sharepoint

I have SharePoint project already exist, and want to add new web parts but I don't want these web parts to be added to already exist feature. I created new feature but I cannot found the required web parts because it's always move to old features in project.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue resolved after setting Feature scope to Site instead of Web